# Resizing Modal and content together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal in JavaScript and style using Less(css), when I make the screen small with dragging this will happen, How I can make the textbox and button shrink as well?

[image]

This is the Less code of Modal:

```
 /* Modal Content/Box */
 .modal-content {
 background-color: @backgroundcolor;
 margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 3px solid @Black;
width: 25%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

This is textbox and button:

```
.forgot-password-textbox {
font-size: @textbox-font-size;
border-radius: @textbox-border-radius;
border: @border-lines solid @Black;
padding: @padding-40 / 4;
width: @textbox-width + 250;
height: @textbox-width/10;
box-shadow: 0 1px @Grey;
 }


.forgot-password-button {
margin-left: @forgot-password-textbox-button-margin-left;
margin-top: auto; 
width: @width-200px;
height: 45px;
 }
```

Comment: did you try changing widths to 100%?

Comment: use max-width instead of width

Comment: @WitVault  I tried this is not working.

Comment: Looks like the container uses a % width while the textbox/button use hard values.  At small window size this will cause issues, try using % width's for the contained elements.  Post a fiddle with your html + css if you want a precise answer.